# If the sum of any two elements in $X$ still belong to $X$, can we conclude that the countably infinite sum of elements also belongs to $X$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, definition

Let $x_1,x_2,...\in X$.

Known that: $x_i,x_j\in X$ implies $x_i+x_j\in X$.

Can we conclude that $x_1+x_2+...+x_n+...\in X$?

I am pretty sure that if the sequence of sum is finite, then the sum must belong to $X$.

What if the sum sequence is countably infinite?

Comment: No. Take $X=\mathbb Q$. Take a sequence $(a_n)$ of rational numbers  increasing to $\sqrt 2$ and let $x_1=a_1,x_n=a_n-a_{n-1}$ for $n >1$.

Comment: No. To add to the great example above, take $X = \mathbb{N}$. Let $(x_n)$ be an arbitrary sequence of natural numbers. Their sum diverges, and certainly isn’t a natural numbers.